# need to update this implementation with promise chaining

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following method in a `ViewModelBuilder` class:

```
async buildViewModel(request)
{
    const bsm = this.getBlogSearchMetadata();
    await this.getBlogPostSearchResults(request);
    await bsm;
    return this.vm;
}
```

This original implementation was designed to allow `getBlogSearchMetadata()` and `getBlogPostSearchResults(request)` to execute at the same time. They both set properties on this.vm and then upon completion of both methods, `buildViewModel` would return this.vm.

I have a new requirement where promise chaining needs to be used in this method. this.getBlogSearchMetadata() needs to return first and a then() promise chain should then call `this.getBlogPostSearchResults(request)` with request values set based on the response from `this.getBlogSearchMetadata()`.

The method code that I provided above reflects the current implementation. Is this enough code for you to describe the specific changes that I can make to the code to support the new requirement? Both subfunctions in the method are marked with the async keyword.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow, this website is not a code writing service, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to best receive help on a specific problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a new requirement where promise chaining needs to be used in this method. this.getBlogSearchMetadata() needs to return first and a then() promise chain should then call this.getBlogPostSearchResults(request)

Simply await `this.getBlogSearchMetadata()`

```
async buildViewModel(request)
{
    // Await 
    const result = await this.getBlogSearchMetadata();

    // now you can use `result`
    await this.getBlogPostSearchResults(request);
    return this.vm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So essentially, async/await and Promises are the exact same thing, they just look different. Here's two examples that work the exact same way:

```
// Promises
yourFunction() {
    yourPromise().then(value => {
        console.log(value);
    });
}


// Async/await
async yourFunction() {
  let value = await yourPromise();
  console.log(value);
}
```

So to chain them, you can effectively use standard promise chaining on your existing async functions without refactoring them.

Upon looking at your code, I forgot to mention: you can await any standard promise as well, it doesn't necessarily have to be an async function.